# Is it constant?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-equations

Let $G$ be an abelian group, and let $n:G\times G\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a map satisfying for all $u,v,w\in G$
$$ n(u+v,w)+n(u,v)=n(u,v+w)+ n(v,w)$$ and $n(0,x)=n(y,0)=0$ for all $x,y\in G$

Is $n$ necessarily a constant?

Comment: What does $1$ stand for?

Comment: The identity element  $e\in G$.

Comment: It appears strange to me to be using multiplicative notation in an Abelian group.

Comment: OK then I will edit it.

Comment: @user426577 Please don't vandalize posts, even if they are your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be the cyclic group of order two, generated by $a$ ($2 a=0$).
Then define $n(u,v)=0$ if $u$ or $v$ are the identity element & $n(a,a)=1$ (or whatever value you like).
There are eight instance of $n(u+v,w)+n(u,v)=n(u,v+w)+ n(v,w)$ to check, and these are all satisfied.

Comment: Thank you so much! there are eight instance but if $u$ or $v$ are zero then they are obvious.

Comment: I wrote the whole table of $8$ possibilities in my notebook ... I cannot see an easy way to shorten the list ?

Comment: If $u$ or $v$ or $w$ are zero, then the first condition follows from the second condition.